# pinmarklet.js to fetch image

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I have used pinmarklet js file to fetch images from web sites.

Is anybody know how the script taking the current page url to fetch images?

I want to pass the url as parameter from php script.

Here is the pinmarklet js URL - http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js

Or
Is there alternate solution in php for above problem?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I create a function on javacript to share custom images with pinterest passing the source of the images that you would like to share and load a PinMarklet with just once request to the API.

Post (spanish): http://www.jspcore.com/pinmarklet-con-imagenes-personalizadas

Code: https://github.com/mustaine/Pinmarklet

Example: http://jspcore.com/code/pinmarklet/index.html

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirement.
I have a Blog list and each blogs(unique URLs) to have pinit button to share all the images.

SO i have to get the images from the URL's . Is there a way to do it ? I am not sure how to read the images from an URL ?

EDIT: Its per page , hence each blog view will have only images present in that blog. 
Blog list will display all images in that current page.

Comment: you can use simple_html_dom element file to fetch images.